# Get hibernate status

Tags: powershell, cmd

Is it possible to get hibernation status using shell ?

I am using `powercfg.exe` to enable/disable it and there doesn't seem to be any way to get the status, even using /Q (query).

I also tried to base that on existence of `%SystemDrive%\hiberfil.sys` but that requires admin rights.

### EDIT

Current solution is [outdated](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/07/23/update-kb4505658-for-windows-10-version-1809-is-out/):

> From version 1809 the registry setting “HibernateEnabled” was renamed “HibernateEnabledDefault”. If you use cmd (powercfg.exe /hibernate off), it is created in addition to the “HibernateEnabledDefault” parameter “HibernateEnabled” with all of the control circuits of the supply.

Setting registry didn't have any effect for me since this version. I had to go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings` to enable it, after that powercfg options worked again. If both `HibernateEnabled` and `HibernateEnabledDefault` are deleted, I still got Hibernate option active.

Comment: try `powercfg /a` . It lists what are the available states. If it lists hibernation, then it is enabled I assume.

Comment: here, https://imgur.com/a/l2Pcwon

Comment: That quoted text about `HibernateEnabled` being renamed `HibernateEnabledDefault` isn't in the main body of the article linked to, it's in one of the comments. If you're using NoScript (like I am), the comments don't show unless you look at a Wayback Machine archived version of that page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check the registry key:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power -name HibernateEnabled
```

Or remotely using .Net and Remote Registry:

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', "ExampleComputer")
$RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Power")
$RegKey.GetValue("HibernateEnabled")
```

Comment: Thx. I was looking at registry and somehow missed that.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this doesn't seem to be enough any more. They key may not exist and Hibernation option is still active. This article also seem to be wrong: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920730/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-hibernation-on-a-computer-that-is-running

Comment: In an admin Powershell in Windows 10 22H2, I try that and get `Get-ItemProperty : Property HibernateEnabled does not exist at path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power.` I can run the command for `HibernateEnabledDefault`, but not for `HibernateEnabled`.

Comment: @AJM Per the additional information in the edit, the registry key did change names in 1809 and that may not be reliable. Parsing the values in the Active Power Plan settings of `GUID: 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e  (Allow hybrid sleep)` and `9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364  (Hibernate after)` may be more reliable. But I have not tested this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative for [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), based on the registry query by [BenH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6788803)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639864):

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power" /v "HibernateEnabled"
```

To capture the result and store it into a variable, use this:

```
for /F "delims=" %V in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power" /v "HibernateEnabled"') do set "Hibernate=%V"
```

Comment: Upvote, but I wonder why did you answer this question and, at the same time, voted to close it as off-topic

Comment: Thanks, @defaultlocale! It's more than a year ago, but I guess I found this question a bit too broad for this site, but I also had a solution in mind; perhaps I thought that my answer could be helpful even when the question becomes migrated to [Super User](https://superuser.com); anyway, I can't recall my motivation I had back then...

Comment: More than two years, actually :) Anyway, I voted to reopen this question as I think powershell programming is perfectly on-topic on SO